# How to animate finite state machine using python and jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, fsm

I am wanting to develop an animated finite state machine in a jupyter notebook. I looked into using graphviz along with https://github.com/mapio/GraphvizAnim but when trying to use this library I keep getting the error "ImportError: No module named gvanim" when using the python2 kernel and "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" when using the python3 kernel. I have installed the package using "pip install https://github.com/mapio/GraphvizAnim/archive/0.2-alpha.zip"

Any other suggestions of how I can accomplish this task?

Comment: If anyone is looking for a solution I had to install graphvizanim specifying python2 -m before and ensure the notebook was run using python2 kernel.

Comment: If you think this question and the solution you found to it are useful for others, you should provide a clear answer to the question yourself and accept it (2 days later). Otherwise delete the question. Answers in the comments let the question stay in the unsolved-list forever.